# How to inject angular app with api url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug, config

I am building an angular app that uses a node api. I need a way to bootstrap the angular code with the url of the node api. I would like the node server to have a config file that holds its own url, which may vary based on dev, test, production, etc (e.g. `http://localhost:4000/api` or `http://www.myproductionbox.com/api/v2`).

What is the best way to get this the url from the server config file and merge it into the angular source code dynamically?

I am using jade for html templates and I can get something to work using those:

`constants.jade`:

```
|angular.module('myApp', []).value('baseUrl', '#{apiBaseUrl}')
```

where `apiBaseUrl` is defined in a config file. The express app renders the jade file like this:

```
app.get('/constants', function(req, res) {
    res.render('constants.jade', { apiBaseUrl: settings.api.baseUrl })
})
```

This works but feels hacky. What's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use an inline `<script>` to hold all those type of config parameters. Such as

```
<script>
  window.config = {
    baseUrl: '#{apiBaseUrl}'
  };
</script>
```

This way your angular app can still live in an external file served from a cdn or something.

And then in your app you do what you were doing before with a slight modification.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).value('baseUrl', window.config.baseUrl)
```

You could also create a `ConfigService` in your app that exposes `window.config`. Then its easier to mock out those values in your tests.